# Does "take a gander" commonly mean "take a chance"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

Question on the term: Take a gander. I've seen and heard it used in two different ways.

1. I'll take a look

> Verb: (idiomatic) To take a look; to check or examine.
>
> They all went downtown to take a gander at the new shops that opened
> there.

[[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_a_gander)]

> 2. I'll take a chance/gamble
>
> Verb: Take a gander is defined as to make an attempt or venture a
> guess.

[[YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/take-a-gander)]

An example of take a gander is when someone asks if you want to try to answer a hard question in a trivia game, or help to solve a puzzle that is being done.

---

Online, I see option 1 to be a more common usage.

Trying to get a feel on how many would or have used it the 2nd way.

Comment: Where did you find the second definition? It's not something I've run across before, and I'm not finding it in any online dictionaries. I wonder if it's somehow a mistaken cross-listing for *take a **gamble*** as they would be very near one another alphabetically in a list of idioms.

Comment: Can you use sense #2 in a sentence? If someone said, "I can't solve this puzzle. Can you help?" and the response was "Sure, I'll take a gander at it," then that is still using sense #1. The person is just offering to take a look at the puzzle.

Comment: I'm thinking that there is another, similar word which might be conflated with "gander" in the second case.  But I can't recall it just now.

Comment: OED doesn't have second meaning, just this: c. A look or glance (see quot. 1914). slang (orig. U.S.). Cf. gander v. 1b.

Comment: @dangph 

Host: You have 4 options, do you have an answer?
Participant: I have no idea
Host: Take a gander at it.
Participant: Let's go for answer A.

I do believe I saw this in a gameshow once, but can't remember the show. 

http://www.yourdictionary.com/take-a-gander with both definitions

Comment: @MarkUbben, thanks, I'd never heard of it used in that sense before. I wonder how YourDictionary does their research. It would be interesting to go the Corpus of Contemporary American English and see how many hits for _gander_ have sense #2. You would get a pretty good, objective answer to your question that way.

Comment: This may be dialect-related, just as "doubt" has shifted meaning in the Indian dialect of English. #2 certainly doesn't seem to be American English. ("Countries divided by our shared language..")

Comment: The only second meaning I'm aware of is to literally pick up a male goose.

Comment: The Wikitionary and Your Dictionary definitions are simply wrong. --There is no rare use of “gander” as a noun or a verb in the meaning of “to take a chance”. It is a direct reference to the gander in a gaggle/flock of geese whose Darwinian duty is to wander around being curious about, and hence looking at, everything, particularly threats, to him and his geese.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second definition appears to be a misunderstanding of the standard definition (as amply documented in [Sven Yargs' answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/390879/177853)). The only "authority" that includes the meaning "take a chance/gamble" for this common idiom is YourDictionary.com, in one of their own (not borrowed) definitions:

> [**take a gander** *verb*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/take-a-gander)
>   Take a gander is defined as to make an attempt or venture a guess.
>
> > *An example of take a gander is when someone asks if you want to try to answer a hard question in a trivia game, or help to solve a puzzle that is being done.*
>
> <sub>YourDictionary definition and usage example. Copyright © 2016 by LoveToKnow Corp</sub>

This online dictionary is largely an aggregator of definitions, but they also include some "original" definitions written by the LoveToKnow staff ([source](http://www.yourdictionary.com/about.html)). I haven't been able to find any information about the qualifications or process of these staff lexicographers. Compare that with [this explanation from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/help/faq-words-into-dictionary) of how words and definitions get into their dictionaries.

In this case, it looks like a writer or writers for YourDictionary have mistaken a phrase meant to convey "*come **take a look at this** [puzzle, so you can help me out with it]*" as meaning "*come **try to solve this** puzzle for me*."

It's easy to see how such a mistake might be made if the writer(s) in question only encountered the phrase in limited circumstances, and it is possible that some other isolated individuals out in the world have made the same mistake and thus mistakenly use the word this way. It is also possible that this mistaken, but easily accessible, definition will drive usage of this novel meaning of the phrase. However, this is *not* currently a standard definition of *take a gander*.

To look for evidence of usage, compare the phrases *take a gander **at*** (the usual collocation) with *take a gander **on*** (which might be expected at least sometimes for a synonym of *take a chance/gamble **on***):

[image: Google Ngram chart showing increasing usage over time of *take a gander at* regardless of capitalization, and no examples of *take a gander on*]

Now, it is possible that the usage is still *at*, with a meaning similar to *take a guess/stab at*. I do find a very few actual examples of *take a gander at this/the puzzle/game* but all of these still appear to be at least consistent with the sense "have a look" (though, again, someone unfamiliar with the phrase might possibly parse one or two of them differently). For example:

> All you constructors out there who put in as many names as you can at every opportunity, **take a gander at this puzzle**. Very tough, but with no junk. ([Comment on blog "Rex Parker Does the NYTimes Crossword Puzzle", January 30, 2016](http://rexwordpuzzle.blogspot.com/2016/01/ancient-collection-of-sanskrit-hymns.html#comment-66304201178704499))
>
> When I say the systems work as a cartel, that might not fully explain things. Let’s **take a gander at the game**’s crafting system and see what I mean. ([Brendan Caldwell, "Premature Evaluation: Crossout", *Rock Paper Shotgun*,  September 19th, 2016](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2016/09/19/crossout-review-early-access/))

Looking for "a gander at" and *gamble* returns results like this:

> Before you can play on the site you ordinarily have the opportunity to **take a gander at the distinctive chances** (for sports betting) at the diverse recreations accessible (for online casinos) or the quantity of players (for poker sites). (["How Online Betting Works – The Basics", gamble-aoiro.com, May 20, 2017](http://www.gamble-aoiro.com/))
>
> Keep reading and **have a gander at some of Marvel’s major misses** on their journey to becoming a powerhouse on the screen. . . . Imagine you’re FOX. You’ve had some major success with the X-Men animated series. You **took a gamble on The Mighty Morphin Power Rangers** and they blew up. What to do next? . . . You make a pilot for a live-action X-Men series that features a crew of hip teenagers. . . . There was buzz at the time that ABC bought the pilot and was going to move forward with a series. It seems they **weren’t even willing to gamble on it**. ([Matt Bromagin, "15 Movies And Shows Marvel Doesn’t Want You To Remember", *The Clever*, May 01, 2017](http://www.theclever.com/15-movies-and-shows-marvel-doesnt-want-you-to-remember/))

That last example juxtaposes the original usage of phrase *take a gander* with the very similar *take a gamble*. Clearly this author knows what the former means, and knows not to use it in the latter's place.

Let me add that these examples are not cherry picked; the first is the only example I could find of "a gander at this puzzle"; I could not find any examples of the phrase with *the puzzle*, *the problem*, *this problem*, or *my problem* (I don't rule out the possibility that they're out there, but Google wasn't showing them to me). The examples with *game* and *gamble* are slightly more numerous (results in the low double digits), but I still didn't spot any examples with the second meaning you cite. I think, from your statement in the question that

> Online, I see option 1 to be a more common usage.

you probably haven't had much luck finding examples of the second usage, either.

To make a too-long story slightly longer, I see no evidence that the definition created by YourDictionary.com is an accurate representation of how this phrase is currently used in any major dialect of English. It's possible for it to shift in meaning, but if such a shift has already begun it is so far still essentially undetectable.

Comment: Interesting answer, especially with regard to the original definitions at YourDictionary.com.

Comment: @SvenYargs I think the writing of the definition almost speaks for itself. I had more commentary on that theme, but took it out as POB. The rest of the answer is just overkill, in case it doesn't speak as loudly to everyone as I think it does.

Comment: I think this extends beyond puzzles to things such as mechanical problems and programming code: "This isn't working. Can you take a gander at it?" "I don't know what's wrong but I'll take a gander." It refers to taking a look, but with the implication that the person will make some attempt to figure out the problem. (You can look at things for various reasons: to help, to judge, to mock, to appreciate their beauty, but "gander" IMO tends to the first.)

Answer (score 9):

Here is the relevant entry from Mitford Mathews, *A Dictionary of Americanisms on Historical Principles* (1951):

> **gander,** *v. intr.* (See quot. 1903.) Also, *to take a gander*, to take a look. Slang. **1903** *Cin[cinnati] Enquirer* 9 May 13/1 Gander—To stretch or rubber your neck. **1947** BASKINS *Dr. Has Baby* 32 Thought I'd take a gander at the offspring. **1948** *Sat[urday] Ev[ening] Post* 17 July 47/2 'Take another gander, Bill,' he suggested dryly.

J.E. Lighter, *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1994) lists three definitions of gander as a verb:

> **gander** *v.* {Orig. S.E., later dial. E} **1.** to wander; ramble. [Instances from 1687 through 1972 omitted.] **2.a.** to crane one's neck for a look; to look.—used intrans. [Instances from 1887 through 1989 omitted.] **b.** to look at; see.—used trans. [Instances from 1936 through 1968 omitted.]

According to Lighter, the noun *gander* has two slang meanings: "a man, esp. away from his home" and "a look."

Amusingly, both Mathews and Lighter note that a *gander party* refers to the male equivalent of a *hen party*—a social gathering exclusively for men. Presumably, at some point, socializing men decided that it was more dignified to be linked to male deer than to male geese.

Barbara Kipfer & Robert Chapman, *Dictionary of American Slang*, fourth edition (2007) has this brief entry for *take a gander*:

> **take a gander *v phr*** To have a look; scrutinize; inspect : *I go over and take a gander into it* (*1914*+)

and this not much longer entry for *gander* as a noun and as a verb:

> **gander *n*** A look; close scrutiny; glance : *I'll have a gander at the prices* (*1887*+) ***v*** : *Want to gander at TV for a while?* (*1914*+) {fr[om] the stretched, gooselike neck of someone gazing intently}

If "take a gander" has acquired the meaning "take a gamble" it must have done so fairly recently, as there is no trace of its use in that sense in any of the slang dictionaries I consulted.

Comment: As I note in a comment beneath an answer posted by OpAmpMagic earlier today, three people in the past 18 months have posted answers attesting to real-world use of "take a gander" to mean "make a guess." The accumulating evidence suggests that the "make a guess" meaning of "take a gander" has a significant following in the U.S. and that slang and idiom dictionaries should take it seriously as a second meaning that constitutes an alternative to the older and far more established "take a look" meaning.

Comment: I have never, in Britain, ever heard it used in the sense of "make a guess". My only experience of its use is as "take a look".

Comment: @WS2 *Taking a gander* always sounds like the livestock crime of *goose-rustling* to me. :) That said, I've never myself heard it meaning a guess not just a look, either, so it's not just Britain.

Comment: @tchrist I'm not entirely clear what you mean. Are you saying it is NOT used in the US to mean "take a look"?

Comment: @WS2 No, I'm saying I've only ever heard it to mean "take a look", not the various solecisms under discussion here.

Comment: @tchrist Ah! Understood. According to the OED it began as US criminal slang - first example 1914.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of option 2 being used in British English. The origins of the word are connected to the head movement of geese. Referring to the nursery rhyme *"Goosey goosey gander where shall I wander ..."*

Comment: Can't say that I've ever heard the second sense in the US either.

Comment: Yes, it's an allusion to the long neck of a goose. Another term, meaning "to take a look" in Britain, is to "take a butcher's". This is from the rhyming slang "butcher's hook". But "gander" is not from rhyming slang, as might be supposed.

Comment: @WS2: I could have saved myself a good minute's googling if I'd scrolled down to your comment first! I ***did*** suppose it might be rhyming slang, so I felt a bit shamefaced when I realised I'd missed the obvious more literal allusion. In my defense I'm not sure I've ever actually seen a real live goose in the flesh, and in the snooker halls of ***my*** misspent youth, we called the relevant cue rest a ***swan-neck*** (which I now realise some people call a ***goose-neck rest***).

Answer (score 2):

I live in America, and my husband just informed me that I’m the only person he’s ever met that uses the phrase “take/make a gander” with the meaning of making a guess. I looked it up and found this site, so I just wanted to let you know someone does regularly use the second option regularly, even if I’m alone on that.

An examples is

> I’ll make a gander and say you aren’t ready to move that, yet.

The sentence I used that started our little debate on the meaning of gander. I use it mainly as a presumptuous guess, never for example as an assertive verb on myself such as “I gander that…” as “guess” is just better.

Comment: Very interesting, and what state or region are you in? It is either a regionalism or was one that has fallen out of use. :)

Comment: Originally US criminal slang - see my comment to tchrist above.

Answer (score 1):

Quite honestly, I feel everyone here used it correctly. The second definition just leaves out the fact that the first definition had already happened, if that makes sense. Because, in order to take a gander (guess) at something, you first had to take a gander (look) at the situation to which the guess is related.
Too many people are looking for shortcuts to things, and this includes communication. When shortcuts happen, important parts of communication are lost in translation, and people end up having misunderstandings. Cuz instead of because. U instead of you. It all matters, in the end.

Think about it. It comes down to feeling you're nuts, or feeling your nuts. The truth is lost in translation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Growing up, I always heard it used to ask if someone wanted to make a guess at answering a puzzle or solving a riddle.

“Would you like to take a gander?,” meaning “Would you like to make a guess?”

Comment: What region did you grow up in?

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "if I had to take a gander" is used almost exclusively in sense 2 (synonymous with "if I had to take a guess"), and it is showing up increasingly often online. I'm from Nevada, and I personally grew up only saying "take a gander" using sense 1, but my wife uses sense 2 much more often. She is from the Pacific Northwest.

Comment: This question has now drawn three answers in the past 18 months that note instances of real-world use of "take a gander" to mean "guess." I am persuaded that this development is not specific to a single person or family, but rather represents a distinct popular usage of the phrase (although certainly not as old or as widespread as the "take a look" meaning). Thanks for your answer!